# Testing Google App Engine app from terminal (python cli)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running `from appname import model`, which gives me:

```
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api
```

So I add the following Python path (the only path I could `find`):

`PYTHONPATH=/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/:~/src/appname/src/ python`

And then I run the command again. But that tells me:

```
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard and the latest GAE. Any tips? All I want to do is run some of the methods in my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From dev_appserver.py:

```
DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
# ...

EXTRA_PATHS = [
  DIR_PATH,
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webob'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'),
]
# ...
sys.path = EXTRA_PATHS + sys.path
```

I think it should work if you put these bits in a separate script, and import it before importing your own code.

Or, as you've pointed out, use the Appengine console in the SDK (but that's not there for Linux users).

Comment: How does that help me? I'm trying to import the packages in the Python CLI (typing `python` in bash) and then testing some stuff.

Comment: @Jonatan: Sorry, I misunderstood. You could have a look at how dev_appserver.py sets up the environment to load an app, and copy the relevant bits of code.

Comment: Ah, that's right. If you update your answer with that info, I'll mark it as correct. On a side note, while it does answer the question I had, another (and in this case the better) answer is simply to click SDK Console and then Interactive Console. I'm so used to running the CLI that I didn't even know this one existed :)

Comment: It looks like dev_appserver adds each folder in lib/ to the path, and lib/yaml/lib/ (this is the lib directory within the appengine SDK; I don't know where it ends up on a mac).

Comment: And on the Linux version, there's nothing to click. ;-)